# Set of generating equations for subtraction.

Tags: universal-algebra

Consider the algebraic structure $(\mathbb{R}, -)$. Is there a finite generating set of equations for subtraction, and if so, can someone exhibit a list of equations.

Comment: I would think that there is no finite generating set. Essentially, you have the same as $\mathbb{R}$ as an abelian group, and it seems any finite set of identities might be satisfiable in some $\mathbb{Z}_p$, for big enough $p$.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf What is the proof there is no finite generating set?

Comment: Well, I was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will give a finite list of identities for this structure.

I will write $\langle A; +, -, 0\rangle$ to mean an abelian
group with binary addition $+$, unary negation $-$,
and *(constant) unary* zero $0(x)$. I am making
$0$ a constant unary operation in order
to avoid discussing nullary operations in this answer.

Before getting to the answer, let me point out
that the equational theory $\mathcal R$ of
the abelian group $\langle \mathbb R; +, -, 0(x)\rangle$
is the same as the equational theory $\mathcal A$
of all abelian
groups, and that theory is axiomatized
by the finite set:

(Associative law) $x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z$.

(Commutative law) $x+y=y+x$.

($0(x)$ is constant) $0(x)=0(y)$.

($0$ is an additive identity element)
$x+0(x)=x$.

(Inverse law)
$x+(-x)=0(x)$.

To see why, observe that
${\mathcal A}\subseteq {\mathcal R}$
because $\langle \mathbb R; +, -, 0\rangle$
is an abelian group. On the other hand,
if $\varepsilon\notin {\mathcal A}$,
then $\varepsilon$ fails in some abelian
group, hence $\varepsilon$
fails in some finitely generated free
abelian group, hence $\varepsilon$ fails in
$\langle \mathbb R; +, -, 0\rangle$,
since $\langle \mathbb R; +, -, 0\rangle$
has free abelian subgroups of all finite ranks.

---

For any abelian group $\langle A; +, -, 0\rangle$
there is an associated 'subtraction structure'
$\langle A; s(x,y)\rangle$ where $s(x,y)=x+(-y)$.
The question asks whether there is a
finite basis for the equational theory of the
subtraction structure
$\langle \mathbb R; s(x,y)\rangle$
associated to $\langle \mathbb R; +, -, 0(x)\rangle$.

There is a dictionary for converting between
the abelian group language and the subtraction language.
Given an abelian group
$\langle A; +, -, 0\rangle$, the associated
subtraction structure is
$\langle A; s_{(+,-,0)}(x,y)\rangle$
where $s_{(+,-,0)}(x,y):= x+(-y)$.
Conversely, given a subtraction structure
$\langle A; s(x,y)\rangle$, the associated
abelian group is
$\langle A; +_s, -_s, 0_s\rangle$
where $0_s(x):=s(x,x)$, $-_s x:=s(0_s,x)=s(s(x,x),x)$,
and $x+_s y := s(x,-_s y)=s(x,s(s(x,x),y))$.

Now I will use this dictionary and the fact that
$\langle \mathbb R; +, -, 0(x)\rangle$
is a finitely based abelian group to derive
that $\langle \mathbb R; s(x,y)\rangle$
is finitely based as a subtraction structure.
I will start with
$\langle \mathbb R; s(x,y)\rangle$,
copy the above finite basis for the
associated abelian group
$\langle \mathbb R; +_s, -_s, 0_s(x)\rangle$
in the $\{s\}$-language using the given dictionary,
then add another identity to say that the
original operation $s(x,y)$ is the subtraction
associated to the abelian group
$\langle \mathbb R; +_s, -_s, 0_s(x)\rangle$.
Result:

(Associative law for $+_s$)
 $s(x,s(s(x,x),s(y,s(s(x,x),z))))=
s(s(x,s(s(x,x),y)),s(s(x,x),z))$.

(Commutative law for $+_s$)
 $s(x,s(s(x,x),y))=s(y,s(s(y,y),x))$.

$(0_s(x)$ is constant)
 $s(x,x)=s(y,y)$.

($0(x)$ is an additive identity element)
$s(x,s(x,x))=x$.

(Inverse law for $-_s$)
 $s(x,s(s(x,x),s(s(x,x),x))))=s(x,x)$.

($s_{(+_s,-_s,0_s)}(x,y)=s(x,y)$)
 $s(x,s(s(x,x),s(s(x,x),y))))=s(x,y)$.