# Is there a finite equational basis for this metric space structure?

Tags: universal-algebra

Consider the algebraic structure $(\mathbb{R};d,0)$, where $d$ is the distance $|x - y|$ between two real numbers. Is there a finite equational basis for the identities of that structure? I conjecture that the commutative law and the equation $d(x,x)=0$ is sufficient. Is it, and if not, is there a further finite basis, or is there no finite basis?

Comment: What is an "equational basis"?

Comment: @LeeMosher A set of equations which generate the equational theory of the structure under logical entailment. See [universal algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra).

Comment: What about $d(0,x)=x$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: Well, that's only true for nonnegative $x$, but you could say $d(0,d(x,y))=d(x,y)$.

Comment: This seems to reduce to the question about finite equational base for the function $abs$ such that $abs(x)=|x|$, and then define $d(x,y)=abs(s(x,y))$, where $s$ is given the finite equational base [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3275695/303170) (to a question of yours). Can that be done without having the order relation defined?